# I am trying to create an app in android to insert data into sql server through a web service.

Tags: android, sql-server, web-services

Hi guys I am new in android here m trying to save some data in sql server from android through a webservice.
I have created a sample app in android and a webservice.
I am getting an exception but i am not able to resolve the exception in java.
Here is the code which i am using.

This is the webservice which i am using.
Its working fine.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace Common.Services
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for AndroidService
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class AndroidService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)
        {
            string strMessage;
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=106.205.11.220;Initial Catalog=mydb;User ID=usernm;Password=passwd");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert INTO android_Sample (SampleName,SampleValue,AddDate) VALUES(@Name,@Value,dateadd(minute,330,getdate()))", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", userInfo.UserName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Value", userInfo.UserAge);
            int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            if (result == 1)
            {
                strMessage = userInfo.UserName + " Details inserted successfully";
            }
            else
            {
                strMessage = userInfo.UserName + " Details not inserted successfully";
            }
            con.Close();
            return strMessage;
        }

        public class UserDetails
        {
            string name = string.Empty;
            string age = string.Empty;

            [DataMember]
            public string UserName
            {
                get { return name; }
                set { name = value; }
            }

            [DataMember]
            public string UserAge
            {
                get { return age; }
                set { age = value; }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

This is the MainActivity.java file.
here i am getting an exception

```
    package tecs.example.wsd;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.SoapFault;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
    import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
    import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity 
    {
         /** Called when the activity is first created. */
            private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/InsertUserDetails";
            private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
            private static String METHOD_NAME = "InsertUserDetails";

            private static String URL = "http://192.168.1.137/common.ui/Services/AndroidService.asmx";

            Button btnSend;
            EditText txtName, txtVal;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            btnSend=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
            txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtText);
            txtVal=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtValue);

            btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
            {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                    //Initialize soap request + add parameters
                    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);        
                    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("UserName");
                    pi.setValue(txtName.getText().toString());
                    pi.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);
                    pi=new PropertyInfo();
                    pi.setName("UserAge");
                    pi.setValue(txtVal.getText().toString());
                    pi.setType(String.class);
                    request.addProperty(pi);
                    //Declare the version of the SOAP request
                    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

                    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
                    envelope.dotNet = true;

                    try {

                        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

                        //this is the actual part that will call the webservice
                        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
// Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
                            SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;



                            if(result != null)
                            {


                                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), result.getProperty(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                txtName.setText("");
                                txtVal.setText("");

                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
                // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
                getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
                return true;
            }

        }
```

I am getting this exception

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.ksoap2.SoapFault

on this line

```
// Get the SoapResult from the envelope body.
SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
```

This is my Manifest file code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="tecs.example.wsd"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="tecs.example.wsd.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my Layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >



    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:hint="@string/Text_Hint" />

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/txtValue"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:hint="@string/Value_Hint" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/btnSend_text" />

</LinearLayout>
```

this is my string values file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">WSD</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="hello_world">Hello world!</string>
    <string name="Text_Hint">Enter Text</string>
    <string name="Value_Hint">Enter Value</string>
    <string name="btnSend_text">Send</string>
</resources>
```

Can anyone help me with this.
what is wrong? 
which is the right method for it? 
How to resolve this error?

Comment: Waht is the result of WebService http://192.168.1.137/common.ui/Services/AndroidService.asmx for InsertUserDetails, I think it is Boolean varaible.or Count

Comment: Akshay Joy i checked the webservice response i guess its string.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <InsertUserDetailsResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <InsertUserDetailsResult>string</InsertUserDetailsResult>
    </InsertUserDetailsResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code Which I used for .Net Web Service

```
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(webRequest);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);


    androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME, envelope);
    Log.d("CheckLogin-SOAP ACTION", SOAP_ACTION + METHOD_NAME);
    SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
    Log.d("CheckLogin - Response", response.toString());

    status= Boolean.valueOf(response.toString());
```

Comment: i tried ur code but its throwing me this exception.

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Common.Services.AndroidService.InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)

I guess those parameters are not getting passed to the web service.

Comment: Hey I have shared sample code to retirve the SAOp response, Tell me waht is the Output of InsertUserDetails () .

Comment: Response is just like Details inserted successfully or Details not inserted.

Comment: Am asking what is the Result of InsertUserDetails when Successfull insertion. what you are expecting in Soap Response

Comment: Ohh Sorry.
That parameter data gets inserted in android_Sample table

Comment: waht you mean, you are sending data through WebService and waht you are trying to achieve with Android Sqlite Db. ok fine

Comment: Check the webservice code which i have posted here.
I simply want to call a webservice from android.

Comment: Tell me waht is the Output of InsertUserDetails () for successfull insertion, Please give me sample the XMl output, then Only you needd to parse XML either by SoapObject and SaopResponse

Comment: I changed the code in web service. Now its working fine.
Thanks!!!
`code`
public string InsertUserDetails(string UserName, string UserAge)
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert INTO android_Sample (SampleName,SampleValue,AddDate) VALUES('" + UserName + "','" + UserAge + "',dateadd(minute,330,getdate()))", con);

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your jar file is `ksoap2-android-assembly-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar` and not `ksoap2-j2me-core-2.1.2.jar` file added into your android project.

Comment: Sorry i didnt mention it.
I have added this jar file in my project.
ksoap2-android-assembly-2.6.5-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: Try Changing `SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;` to `Object result = envelope.getResponse();`

Comment: I changed the code as u told but now its giving me this exception 

SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Common.Services.AndroidService.InsertUserDetails(UserDetails userInfo)

I guess there is some problem in parameters seems lyk they are not getting sent or sumthin.

Comment: Try to send in the parameter as string to see if the data is atleast reaching the webmethod. Also dont forget to add `result.tostring()` to get the result.